# Does a whine at the end of the pumping cycle indicate pump failure?

Tags: sump-pump

The normal cycle for our pump in spring runs 25 seconds every 5-10 minutes.   For 8 months of the year it runs a couple times a day.  It's set up without a check valve so the line doesn't freeze where it exits the house.  The line outside the house dumps into a 20 foot length of sewer line at a 10 degree slope to take it away from the foundation.

Anyway, of late the pump makes a high pitched whine for about the last 7 seconds of its pumping cycle. There doesn't appear to be any change in the discharge rate.

Ideas?

Comment: Is it drawing air at that point due to a poor float configuration?

Comment: If it did that the water flow would be much reduced at the end of the cycle wouldn't it?

Comment: I'd think so. Something changes when the sound changes. Just throwing darts in the dark.